# Grafana behind NGINX reverse proxy and auth_request

Tags: linux, authentication, nginx, grafana

I've got Grafana running on port 2000, and a rails app (Puma dev server) running on port 3000 with the following Nginx config:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name *.localhost.test;
        location /{
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
        location /grafana {
                auth_request /authenticate_grafana;
                auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_webauth_user;
                proxy_set_header x-webauth-user $user;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:2000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

This works really well, with the rails app returning a 200 from /authenticate_grafana if the cookies passed through match. Unfortunately it only seems to work with GET requests?
[![screenshot of post request][1]][1]
POST requests take exactly 30s (i.e. a timeout of some kind) and NGINX returns a 500.
Sometimes the NGINX error log shows:

```
2021/08/18 17:46:51 [error] 94438#94438: *781 auth request unexpected status: 408 while sending to client, client: 192.168.3.1, server: *.localhost.test, request: "POST /grafana/api/frontend-metrics HTTP/1.1", host: "test-org.localhost.test", referrer: "http://test-org.localhost.test/grafana/?orgId=1"
```

Sometimes this is logged

```
2021/08/18 17:49:47 [error] 94438#94438: *862 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.3.1, server: *.localhost.test, request: "POST /grafana/api/frontend-metrics HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/authenticate_grafana", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/authenticate_grafana", host: "test-org.localhost.test", referrer: "http://test-org.localhost.test/grafana/?orgId=1"
2021/08/18 17:49:47 [debug] 94438#94438: *862 http next upstream, 2
2021/08/18 17:49:47 [debug] 94438#94438: *862 free rr peer 2 4
2021/08/18 17:49:47 [warn] 94438#94438: *862 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.3.1, server: *.localhost.test, request: "POST /grafana/api/frontend-metrics HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/authenticate_grafana", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/authenticate_grafana", host: "test-org.localhost.test", referrer: "http://test-org.localhost.test/grafana/?orgId=1"
```

And sometimes neither of these are logged it seems.
Could anyone advise the best way to debug this please? It's rather odd that GETs are fine but POSTs are not, could it be a Referrer policy/cookies thing?
Thanks all!

EDIT:

Diffing the GET and POST headers shows that the POST request includes the `Origin` header whereas the GET does not, could this be the problem?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn0Us.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted!
Needed to modify my config to:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name *.localhost.test;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

        location = /authenticate_grafana {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass_request_body off;
                proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }

        location /grafana {
                auth_request /authenticate_grafana;
                auth_request_set $user $upstream_http_x_webauth_user;
                proxy_set_header x-webauth-user $user;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```